# cordova-plugin-fcm android icon not working

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working with this plugin and it works great, however on Android (6.0) I can't seem to get my icon to work. This is the result when I send a push notification.

[bad icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM5gZ.png)

I tried adding the fcm_push_icon.png to the following folders but it still doesn't show.
res/drawable-hdpi
res/drawable-mdpi
res/drawable-ldpi
res/drawable-xhdpi
res/drawable-xxhdpi
res/drawable-xxxpi

Am I missing something?